# Rectangular Venn diagrams/Euler Diagram in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to put together a Rectangular Venn Diagram in D3.js. Such as this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram#/media/File:Euler_diagram_of_solar_system_bodies.svg

However I am finding it really hard to know where to start. I looked at: https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/ 
But it only seems to work for circular venn diagrams.

I looked at this paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.5101&rep=rep1&type=pdf specifically on page 9 but the math is a bit over my head. There is mention of a java program which i tried to look for to better understand but i could not find it anywhere.

Can anyone point me to a good resource or give a code example of how to construct a rectangular Venn diagram(Or Euler diagram not too sure on the terminology)?

Comment: Is it similar to D3 treemap? https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/treemap.html and https://observablehq.com/@d3/treemap

Comment: Or the nested treemap like https://observablehq.com/@d3/nested-treemap

Comment: @Coola Quite similar except i need to be able to share sets such as in the first part of this picture: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/VennDiagram_900.gif where A ∩ B is both in set A and B